# genymotion emulator above 5.0 API 21 my app freezes with facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, emulation, genymotion

I have an issue of login with facbook sdk in my app, it works with genymotion emulator 5.0 API 21.0 and on my real device(One plus 7 pro) but when I want to login with an emulator above 5.0 API 21.0, there is a freeze which appears (see picture below).

I use genymotion Desktop version : 3.2.1 and VirtualBox version : 6.1.34

[image]

Below my LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityLoginBinding binding;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForResult = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_SignInActivity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        setContentView(view);
        FacebookSdk.setClientToken(String.valueOf(R.string.facebook_client_token));
        this.handleResponseAfterSignIn();
        this.setupListeners();
    }

    private void handleResponseAfterSignIn() {
        startForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {

            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                // userManager.createUser();
                startMainActivity();

            } else if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Utils.showSnackBar(binding.loginLayout, getString(R.string.snackbar_msg_login_cancelled));
            } else {
                Utils.showSnackBar(binding.loginLayout, getString(R.string.snackbar_msg_error_unknow));
            }
        });
    }


    // Launching Profile Activity
    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setupListeners() {

        binding.bntLoginFacebook.setOnClickListener(v -> signInWith("facebook"));

        binding.bntLoginGoogle.setOnClickListener(v -> signInWith("google"));

        binding.bntLoginEmail.setOnClickListener(v -> signInWith("email"));

    }


    private void signInWith(String provider) {
        //AuthUI provider
        AuthUI.IdpConfig authUiConfig;

        // Choose authentication providers
        switch (provider) {
            case "facebook":
                authUiConfig = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build();
                break;
            case "google":
                authUiConfig = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build();
                break;
            default:
                authUiConfig = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build();
                break;
        }

        Intent intentLogin = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(Collections.singletonList(authUiConfig))
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false, true)
                .build();
        startForResult.launch(intentLogin);
    }
```

My build.gradle App:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    ///FIREBASE///
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    // FIREBASE UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'
    //FACEBOOK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:13.2.0'
}

I tried to use  firefox, chrome, opera ... and others browsers from playstore but always the same problem.

If someone can help me :-) it'll be very kind

Thanks for your answers
Best Regards
```